# Difference between Gazebo & Moveit!

Tags: ros, quadcopter, motion-planning, gazebo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm planning to do do motion planning for a quadcopter but I'm still confused concerning the software that I should use.
Could someone explain to me the difference between gazebo and ROS?  The only explanation I found was:

"Gazebo is a 3D simulator, while ROS serves as the interface for the robot. Combining both results in a powerful robot simulator."
But it is still not clear for me!

I would like also to know which one is more suitable for motion planning of a quad among the following list: (Gazebo, Ros moveit, or V-rep or may be matlab ), I'm sorry, but I'm really confused, and there were no enough information to be able to distinguish the difference between each one of them.

So I would like to know what is the difference between the ones mentioned above and for what reasons would one want to use gazebo over ROS or V-rep and vice versa?

I would really appreciate any clarification about the subject!
Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/208851/difference-between-gazebo-&-moveit!!!/) by [Mark54](https://answers.ros.org/users/22370/mark54/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2015-05-08

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

These are NOT replacements for each other. Gazebo, ROS, and MoveIt serve completely different purposes.

Gazebo is a simulator, it doesn't do any motion planning.
ROS is (in this context) the middleware that allows gazebo to talk to other software.
MoveIt is a motion planning framework that uses ROS to talk to Gazebo.

If you want to do motion planning, use moveit.

If you want to test these motion plans without an actual robot, replace that robot with a simulated one in gazebo.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2015-05-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mark54](https://answers.ros.org/users/22370/mark54/) on 2015-05-08**:
Thank you very much for your answer that was helpful!

**Comment by [alexi](https://answers.ros.org/users/24636/alexi/) on 2015-10-21**:
which will be better simulator gazebo or V Rep for manipulators ?

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2015-10-21**:
@alexi please don't use `comment` section to ask a new question (questions in comment section don't even get much attention).